# for loop for merging multiple *.gpkg files in OSGeo4W Shell

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, osgeo4w, gdal-merge

I´d like to merge multiple files (geopackages) saved in a Windows folder
to one *.gpkg using OSGeo4W Shell:

```
  for %f in (\*.gpkg) do (ogr2ogr 'gpkg' -update -append merged.gpkg %f -nln merged.gpkg)
  for %f in (dir\*.gpkg) do (ogr2ogr 'gpkg' -update -append merged.gpkg %f)
```

I don´t get any errors but in the folder nothing happens.
For merging multiple layers in the OSGeo4W Shell I can use:

```
ogr2ogr merged.shp input1.shp
ogr2ogr -update -append merged.shp input2.shp -nln merged
```

but this is very time-consuming since I have hundreds of layers.

How can I do this?

Update according to @user30184 and @Frau Schmidt:

```
for %f in (*.gpkg) do (ogr2ogr 'gpkg'  --debug -update -append merged.gpkg %f -nln merged.gpkg)
```

Error: Couldn't fetch requested layer

Comment: Does each GeoPackage in `*.gpkg` contain only one feature table?

Comment: @user30184 yes.

Comment: And tables in different gpkg files have similar attributes with same names and data types, right? Are even the names of the feature tables the same?

Comment: Identical structure of the attribute table, identical names, data types, etc. Everything is considered for merging. Of course it can be done via a standard tool in a GIS but I´d like to do this extra in the shell cause of administration and performance reasons.

Comment: I would first test the DO part and fix the errors `ogr2ogr - 'gpkg' -update -append merged.gpkg %f -nln merged.gpkg ERROR 6: Unknown option name '-'`.

Comment: try to give the ogr2ogr command the parameter --debug. So you can see, if here are any errors

Comment: Modified the code ("-" error + --debug): "Couldn't fetch requested layer" as response. I suppose there must be sthg wrong with the for loop...